# Implementing get_walltime in Fortran

Tags: time, fortran

I'm writing a Fortran program based on the first exercise in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d45e/c41b45caa8686fa1788d9191ab4044a18a83.pdf) book (page 34). The book is designed as an introduction to high performance computing. The first exercise asks the user to write code to estimate pi. Following what is provided by the authors, I have done this successfully.

```
program compute_pi
   double precision :: x, delta_x, sum
   !double precision :: S,E,MFLOPS
    integer, parameter :: SLICES=10000000
    sum = 0.d0 ; delta_x = 1.d0/SLICES
    !call get_walltime(S)
    do i=0,SLICES-1
        x = (i+0.5)*delta_x
        sum = sum + 4.d0 / (1.d0 + x*x)
    enddo
    pi = sum*delta_x 
    print *, pi
    !call get_walltime(E)
    !MFLOPS = R*N*2.d0/((E-S)*1.d6)
end program compute_pi
```

Next, I am trying to compute performance in MFlops/sec. In order to do this, I have followed the author's example on page 5 and wrote

```
program compute_pi
   double precision :: x, delta_x, sum
   double precision :: S,E,MFLOPS
    integer, parameter :: SLICES=10000000
    sum = 0.d0 ; delta_x = 1.d0/SLICES
    call get_walltime(S)
    do i=0,SLICES-1
        x = (i+0.5)*delta_x
        sum = sum + 4.d0 / (1.d0 + x*x)
    enddo
    pi = sum*delta_x 
    print *, pi
    call get_walltime(E)
    MFLOPS = R*N*2.d0/((E-S)*1.d6)
end program compute_pi
```

When I run the above code in Netbeans (the IDE I am using for Fortran), it returns

```
undefined reference to `get_walltime_'
```

I'm not sure why the reference is undefined.

Comment: Where do you think the subroutine `get_walltime` is defined, and how do you tell the linker about it?

Comment: Whatever the book is it has failed to teach you one important, and very elementary, lesson - always include the line `implicit none` in Fortran programs.  In the case of your examples, put the line immediately after the `program` line.  The lack of `implicit none` is not the cause of the error you report, but it is the cause of a subtle semantic error you haven't found yet.  And it will be the cause of many errors you encounter in future if you fail to heed my dire warning.

Comment: I might have to make my own method for `get_walltime` similar to `void get_walltime_(double*wcTime) {
 struct timeval tp;
 gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
 *wcTime = (double)(tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec/1000000.0);
}`

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while since I read that book), Hager and Wellein implemented the `get_walltime` in C. The sources should be in the book. Ah, just found it - it's the snippet you gave above. Please give proper attribution.

Comment: What is this routine supposed to do? Maybe there is a intrinsic in Fortran for it.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I would personally use the OpenMP/MPI versions of get_walltime. [OpenMP is much simpler]

Comment: The author provides C code for `get_walltime` on page 6. I tried implementing that but couldn't get it to work in Fortran. I'm going to see if I can find an implementation of `get_walltime` in Fortran. There are many ways of measuring system time, the author must want students to learn how to implement MFlops/sec by writing their own method.

Comment: I can't see any reason why not to use `system_clock()`. Probably the book is just too old. If you really wish so, you could write your `get_walltime` with `system_clock` inside.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM_005fCLOCK.html this would work, as Vladimir F says, assuming the netbeans is using gfortran as compiler

Comment: @yosukesabai: Any compiler supporting Fortran 90 or newer must provide the system_clock intrinsic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pure Fortran implementation of get_walltime (only compile-tested):

```
subroutine get_walltime(wctime)
  use iso_fortran_env, only: int64
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
  real(dp) :: wctime
  integer(int64) :: r, c
  call system_clock(c, r)
  wctime = real(c, dp) / r
end subroutine get_walltime
```

Even better, put it into a module to get interface checking for free. Or even better than that, just call system_clock directly.

Comment: Note that system_clock is very low precision on Windows (at least with intel fortran). One reliable alternative is to compile with OPENMP and use !$ OMP_GET_WTIME(). [or if linking with MPI use MPI_WTime()].

Answer (score 0):

The `get_wallclock()` in that exercise is a call to a C-code that calculated wall-clock time using `gettimeofday()` from `<sys/time.h>`. Flip to page 6 of the same book for an example on how to implement that function. Afterwards, compile your C-code with the `-c` flag to get the object file, e.g. get_wallclock.o. Then link your main Fortran program to the object file. This way the linker can resolve `get_walltime()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: I did not try commenting any post, I simply wrote an answer, and I think it does in fact answer the question. Axion004 asks why the compiler returns "undefined reference" error, and my answer simply is because get_walltime() function is not yet implemented. But I agree, it is not 100% clear in my earlier post.